# Write a procedure loadDocument(String name) which will load and analyze lines after lines searching for link in every line

Tags: java, string

> Write a procedure `loadDocument(String name)` which will load and analyze lines after lines searching for link in every line. The link format is as follows: 5 characters `link=` (it can be mixed capital and small letters) after which there is a correct identifier. The correct identifier starts from letter (small or capital) follows by zero or more occurrences of letters or digits or underline `_`. The procedure has to print subsequent identifiers, each one in a separated line. Before printing, the identifiers have to be changed to small letters. The document ends with line with the text `eod`, which means end of document.

My code:

```
public static void loadDocument(String name, Scanner scan) {
    while(scan.hasNext()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        if(line.equals("eod")) {
            return;
        }
        else if(line.matches("link="+name) && correctLink(name)) {
            String identifier = name.toLowerCase();
            System.out.println(identifier);
        }
        else
            continue;
    }            
}

// accepted only small letters, capital letter, digits and '_' (but not on the begin)
public static boolean correctLink(String link) {
    if(link.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+[0]+||[0-9]+||_"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

How to write if line equal to `link=`, return whatever's after `link=`?
My problem is in this code:

```
else if(line.matches("link="+name) && correctLink(name)) {
    String identifier = name.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(identifier);
}
```

For example, if the input is `link=abc`, I want it to print `abc`.

Comment: `else continue;` not needed and you can simply do `return line.matches("link="+name) && correctLink(name);`

Comment: I suggest you start with properly formatting your code: apply the correct indentation, so the structure of the code is easy to see.

Comment: Decompose your problem properly.  I'd separate loading the document from the search for the list of links.  I'd write two methods: one that takes in a file and returns a List<String> of lines, and another that takes in the List<String> of document lines and returns a List<String> of links.

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest that you get used to compare to literal strings "the other way round" - this will save you from a lot `NullPointerException`s (but this is just a side comment):

```java
if ("eod".equals(line))
```

You can use @Ofer s example (it is generated from https://regex101.com, a nice page to play around with regular expressions and get them explained btw.) but you should use a different regex:

```java
final String regex = "link=([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)";
```

and a different option for the pattern:

```java
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

I used the CASE_INSENSITIVE option to make the "link" also trigger for mixed case writings (like "Link", "liNk" and so on). Therefore I also could skip the uppercase letters from the actual regex, as [a-z] will also match uppercase letters with that option, and that's what was requested.

The "magic" here is that you put the expression that you later want to "read" from the pattern matcher into parenthesis "()" - this marks a "group". Group 0 always gives back the full match (including the "link=" here).

You can play around with that expression at https://regex101.com/r/id2CP2/1

Please don't forget to convert the identifiers (you get them from `matcher.group(i)`) to lowercase before you output them.